# Can I create and relate two nodes with the same name but different ids in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created two nodes in neo4j with the same name and label but with different ids:

```
CREATE (P:names {id:"1"})
CREATE (P:names{id:"2"})
```

My question is if I can create a relationship between these two nodes like this:

```
MATCH (P:names),(P:names) 
WHERE P.id = "1" AND P.id = "2" 
CREATE (P)-[r:is_connected_with]->(P) RETURN r"
```

I try it but it doesn't work.
Is it that I shouldn't create nodes with the same name or there is a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following?

First run the create statements:

```
CREATE (p1:Node {id:"1"}) // note, named p1 here
CREATE (p2:Node {id:"2"})
```

Then, do the matching:

```
MATCH (pFirst:Node {id:"1"}), (pSecond:Node {id:"2"}) // and here we can call it something else
CREATE pFirst-[r:is_connected_with]->(pSecond)
RETURN r
```

Basically, you are matching two nodes (with the label `Node`). In your match you call them `p1` and `p2` but you can change these identifiers if you wish. Then, simply create the relationship between them.

You should **not** create identifiers with the same name. Also note that `p1` and `p2` are not the *name* of the node, it is the name of the identifier in this particular query.

**EDIT:** After input from the OP I have created a [small Gist that illustrates some basics regarding Cypher](http://gist.neo4j.org/?56d62f58b9d1a9117564).

Comment: Yes this works. What doesn't seem to work is when the names of the two nodes is the same (e.g. p instead of p1 and p2).

Comment: But, Pseudo is not at real name of the node - it is the name you give it in the specific query.

Comment: Sorry the naming in my question was confusing. I edited it. So I shouldn't use the same name for my nodes even if there is an id that makes them unique? This can be quite tricky when I have to generate thousands of nodes.

Comment: Create a node with a name: `create (p:Person {id:"id", name:"Tom"})`. Now you have created a Person-node with the name "Tom", the id "id". The label of the node is "Person". The id is decided by you - neo4j keeps their own unique node ids. You can create as many "Tom" as you like. The node identifier in the query is "p" and should not have duplicates in the same query

Comment: So for eeach node that I create the p (from your example) has to be different. Something like p1,p2,p3... right?

Comment: Yes, if you are creating them in the same query.

Comment: @dkar - I have added a gist that you can check if you feel like it. Take a look at [this](http://gist.neo4j.org/?56d62f58b9d1a9117564) to learn some of the basics.

Answer (score 3):

@wassgren has the right answer about how to fix your query but I might be able to fill in some details about why and it's too long to leave in a comment.

The character before the colon when describing a node or relationship is referred to as an identifier, it's just a variable representing a node/rel within a Cypher query. Neo4j has some naming conventions that you are not following and as a result, it makes your query harder to read and will be harder for you to get help in the future. Best practices are:

- Identifiers start lowercase: `person` instead of `Person1`, `p` instead of `P`
- Labels are singular and have their first character capitalized: `(p1:Name)`, not `(p1:Names)` or `(p1:names)` or `(p1:name)`
- Relationships are all caps, `[r:IS_CONNECTED_WITH]`, not `[r:is_connected_with]`, though this one gets broken all the time ;-)

Back to your query, it both won't work and it doesn't follow conventions.

Won't work:

```
MATCH (P:names),(P:names) 
WHERE P.id = "1" AND P.id = "2" 
CREATE (P)-[r:is_connected_with]->(P) RETURN r
```

Will work, looks so much better(!):

```
MATCH (p1:Name),(p2:Name) 
WHERE p1.id = "1" AND p2.id = "2" 
CREATE (p1)-[r:IS_CONNECTED_WITH]->(p2) RETURN r
```

The reason your query doesn't work, though, is that by writing `MATCH (P:names),(P:names) WHERE P.id = "1" AND P.id = "2"`, you are essentially saying "find a node, call it 'P', with an ID of both 1 and 2." That's not what you want and it obviously won't work!

If you're trying to create many nodes, you would rerun this query for each pair of nodes you want to create, changing the ID you assign each time. You can create the nodes and their relationship in one query, too:

```
CREATE (p1:Name {id:"1"})-[r:IS_CONNECTED_WITH]->(p2:Name {id:"2"}) RETURN r
```

In the app, just change the ID you want to assign to the nodes before you run the query. The identifiers are instance variables, they disappear when the query is complete.

**EDIT #1!**

One more thing, setting the `id` property within your app and assigning it to the database instead of relying on the Neo4j-created internal ID **is** a best practice. I suggest avoiding sequential IDs and instead using something to create a unique ID. In Ruby, many people use `SecureRandom::uuid` for this, I'm sure there's a parallel in whatever language(s) you are using.

**EDIT #2!**

Neo4j supports integer properties. `{id:"1"}` != `{id: 1}`. If your field is supposed to be an integer, use an integer.

Comment: Thanks for your very useful comment. Especially for the last sentence. It wasn't clear to me that the identifiers disappear after.